# how to show <?php ..?> opening tag and closing tag in browser which are saved in a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a php online exam page, I have saved all my data in a table 
[image]

Now i want to show question and answers options in browser
I tried the following but not working

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Exam Paper </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php $ecourse_id = '3';
    sc_select(questions_data,"select equestion_id,question,correct_option,marks_allocated,option_1,option_2,option_3,option_4 from sri_dev_mob.cms_elearning_questions where ecourse_id='$ecourse_id'");
    $count = {questions_data}->RecordCount();
    if($count>0)
    {
        $seq = 1;
        foreach($questions_data as $record){
        extract($record);
            echo $seq.')'.$question."<br>";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='$seq' value='$option_1'>".$option_1."<br>";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='$seq' value='$option_2'>".$option_2."<br>";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='$seq' value='$option_3'>".$option_3."<br>";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='$seq' value='$option_4'>$option_4 <br>";
            $seq++;
        }


    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly is not working?

Comment: in browser options are not showing ie record and and record 2 from my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below solution

Use **htmlspecialchars()** function

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='$seq' value='$option_1'>".htmlspecialchars($option_1)."<br>";
```